# n+1 th fibonacci term

Tags: combinatorics, combinations, fibonacci-numbers

Hello I was trying to prove

$$\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n}^{} \binom{n-k}{k} = \operatorname{Fib}_{n+1}$$
which the approach I made was

1. Prove that it holds for $n=0$, $n=1$.
2. Then use the fact that sum of $n-1$-th and the $n$-th term is $n+1$-th term.

I easily showed 1) but am confused about 2) can anyone give me approach for proving second part?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use the recursive definition of Fib. numbers.

Comment: Try to use latex for the equation which increases readability, instead of  giving image,

Comment: What happened when you tried the sum of the two sums and then simplified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$Fib_{n + 2} = Fib_{n} + Fib_{n + 1}$$

You have already shown the base case and assume the inductive hypothesis to be true.

Also, note that $$\binom{n}{k} = 0$$ for $k > n$.
And, $$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n - 1}{k - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{k}$$

Now, $$Fib_{n + 2} = Fib_{n + 1} + Fib_{n}$$
$$=\binom{n}{0} + \binom{n - 1}{1} + \binom{n - 2}{2} + \cdots + \binom{0}{n} + \binom{n - 1}{0} + \binom{n - 2}{1} + \cdots + \binom{0}{n - 1}$$
$$=\binom{n}{0} + (\binom{n - 1}{1} + \binom{n - 1}{0}) + (\binom{n - 2}{2} + \binom{n - 2}{1}) + \cdots + (\binom{0}{n} + \binom{0}{n - 1})$$
$$= \binom{n}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n - 1}{2} + \cdots + \binom{1}{n}$$
$$= \binom{n + 1}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n - 1}{2} + \cdots + \binom{1}{n} + \binom{0}{n + 1}$$
$$=\sum_{0 \leq k \leq n + 1}^{} \binom{n + 1-k}{k}$$

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. I have also added a combinatorial proof for this, you can try to understand which one you like.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a combinatorial proof for this.

Consider the following:

> What are the number of sequences $[b_1, b_2, \cdots, b_n]$ such that $b_i$ is either $0$ or $1$ and none of the $0$'s are adjacent.

$$\textbf{First Way}$$

One way to count this is using recursion.

Let $f_i$ denote the number of valid sequences of length $i$. $$f_0 = 1$$
$$f_1 = 2$$ and $$f_i = f_{i - 1} + f_{i - 2}$$ Why? There are two possible scenarios for the $i$th element:

$1.$ Either it is $0$. Then, the previous element HAS to be $1$. The number of remaining sequences is $f_{i - 2}$.

$2.$ Either it is $1$. Then, the previous sequence has no restriction, so add $f_{i - 1}$.

**Note that $f_i$ is just the $(i + 2)$th Fibonacci element.**

$$\textbf{Second Way}$$

Another way to count this is using the theorem:

> The number of ways of picking $k$ elements from $[a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n]$ such that none of the $k$ elements are adjacent is $\binom{n - k + 1}{k}$.

Iterate on the number of $0$s and count.

This is $$\binom{n + 1}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n - 1}{3} + \cdots + \binom{1}{n}$$

Add $\binom{0}{n + 1}$ for the sake of completeness and it doesn't change the value.

$$S_{n + 1} = \binom{n + 1}{0} + \binom{n}{1} + \binom{n - 1}{3} + \cdots + \binom{1}{n} + \binom{0}{n + 1}$$

Since the two methods count the same thing:

$$S_{n + 1} = f_n = Fib_{n + 2}$$

Since $n$ is just a variable, $$S_n = Fib_{n + 1}$$